# Queston on probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider the space $\Omega=\{1,2,3,...\}$, and we assign probability measure on it in such a way that each of them has an 'equal probablity'. Then, we get $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(X=i)=0$, due to each element has measure $0$. But on the other hand, $P(X\in \Omega)=1$. According to the definition of probability measure, they should be the same. What goes wrong, please?

Answer (score 4):

What you just proved is that there is no probability $P$ on $\Omega$ such that for all $m,n$ $P(\{m\})=P(\{n\})$.